# How to use jsx on vuejs3 without build ,using the in browser standalone

Tags: javascript, vuejs3

How can i use jsx in vue3 ,in the in browser compiler
is there any way to compile jsx code usong the vue standalone version

Answer (score 0):

JSX is not processable in the browser. You can use the `h` function or a parser like [htm](https://github.com/developit/htm).

https://vuejs.org/guide/extras/render-function.html